# Safari with FCM Push notifications

Tags: firebase, push-notification, safari, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We implemented push notifications using FCM in chrome and firefox and it worked fine, but In Safari we are getting following error:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).

Did anyone deal with this kind of issues? any suggestions?

Comment: As the error says [Safari doesn't support web push](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api), which FCM relies on for browser support. So that means that Safari can't receive FCM notifications.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) is quite explicit about this:

> The FCM JavaScript API lets you receive notification messages in web apps running in browsers that support the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/). This includes the browser versions listed in this [support matrix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api).

As the error says (and the caniuse.com support matrix confirms) [Safari doesn't support web push](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api), which FCM relies on for browser support. So that means that Safari can't receive FCM notifications.

Comment: Safari 12 does suppoprt push notifications, with their "own" implementation. Are we supposed to believe that Google does not have enough budget to hire a programmer to implement their implementation for Firebase?

Comment: If you check the support matrix on caniuse.com, it shows that Safari 12 still doesn't support the push API: https://caniuse.com/#search=push

Comment: Frank, caniuse.com is outdated in this case: See the Preferences dialog from Safari 12: https://photos5.appleinsider.com/gallery/26524-37870-safari-notifications-permission00004-l.jpg

Comment: @andreszs Safari may support push notifications, but that doesn't mean they support Web Notifications (which is a standard). Last time I checked, Safari used its own implementation and that's what Frank is saying?

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment anymore. I mistakenly wrote "Web Notifications" where i meant "Push API". It isn't even listed on their [Webkit Features](https://webkit.org/status/) page so it's either not going to happen at all or it's going to take a loooong time :(